# "expand/collapse all" works, but only after the item has been manually expanded once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a script to hide my listviews/list-dividers to match the filter, so that when expanded, only the matched li's show.

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle(function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

      },function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

with this css

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
.listIcon{
  float:right
}
```

and then I have some expand/collapse all code:

```
    <script>
  $(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function () {
    var collapseAll = this.id == "btnCollapse";
    if (collapseAll) {
        $(".ui-li-divider .ui-icon-minus").click();
    } else {
        $(".ui-li-divider .ui-icon-plus").click();
    }
});
    </script>
```

with this to trigger it

```
        <div class="ui-grid-a ui-mini">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><a id="btnExpand" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all collapseExpand">Expand All</a></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><a id="btnCollapse" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all collapseExpand">Collapse All</a></div>
</div>
```

and then the html is like this:

```
    <li data-role="list-divider" data-link="Crabclan">Crab Clan<span class="fiveringsdb"><span class="icon-clan-crab"></span></span></li>

    <li class="hidden Crabclan" data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01031:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crab:Borderlands Defender:t.Bushi"><a><div><img src="img/l5r01031.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>
    <li class="hidden Crabclan" data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01025:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crab:Eager Scout:t.Bushi:t.Scout"><a><div><img src="img/l5r01025.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>

...

    <li data-role="list-divider" data-link="Craneclan">Crane Clan<span class="fiveringsdb"><span class="icon-clan-crane"></span></span></li>

    <li class="hidden Craneclan" data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01040:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crane:Asahina Artisan:t.Shugenja:t.Air"><a><div><img src="img/l5r01040.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>
    <li class="hidden Craneclan" data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01050:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crane:Asahina Storyteller:t.Courtier:t.Shugenja:t.Air:k.Sincerity"><a><div><img src="img/l5r01050.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>
    <li class="hidden Craneclan" data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01042:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crane:Brash Samurai:t.Bushi"><a><div><img src="img/l5r01042.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>
```

The problem is, expand all only works once I've already manually expanded the list dividers. If I try it on first load it does nothing. But manually open a few dividers, close them again, and it'll happily open and close those on every click.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have complicated too much this simple work

Comment: @GüneySaramalı Which bit am I overcomplicating? If it's the script to show/hide - after a lot of trial, error and searching, that's the only solution I could come up with to properly filter a collapsible list - most methods filter the list dividers but then show every <LI> beneath, rather than just the filtered <LI> as this one does.

Comment: is this what you are trying to achive? http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=d6e8366ec8b7f00cd0c2ce63e126ad50

Comment: @GüneySaramalı The expand/contract all works - except that it opens everything, ignoring the filter. The one I'm using expands all the list dividers, but maintains the filter, so even with expand all, only the filter returned results display.

Comment: So what is the var you want to filter?

Comment: @GüneySaramalı I want to filter for anything in the data-filtertext. ie data-filtertext="p.core:l5r01040:Character:d.Dynasty:c.Crane:Asahina Artisan:t.Shugenja:t.Air">  so in the code I posted above, typing "Asahina" into the filter will hide the Crab Clan list divider, and show only the Crane Clan - and THEN, when I expand all - The Crane clan <LI>'s will only show the first two entries, which match Asahina, and won't show the third, which doesn't.  My code handles all that - except for the original probelm, expand contract only kicks in after list dividers have been manually opened once.

Comment: I found a partial, but not very satisfactory answer. If I add <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow listIcon"> to each list-divider, instead of my custom icons (<span class="fiveringsdb"><span class="icon-clan-crab"></span></span>) etc, then expand/contract works perfectly - but that means I'm stuck with + & - icons instead of the custom ones for each clan. So it works, but I'm not happy about it :D

Comment: Sory but you didnt even shared the input that you type yout filter inside. How could you except us to create your that. You questiın is missing in code and explanation as well thats my best with this question.